# How to render_template and then redirect to external URL in Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to redirect a user to a web page with a loading spinner using render_template and then redirect them to an external URL using `flask` in Python.

I have written the code below, it only waits 3 seconds and then redirects to `youtube.com`.

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def redirect_to_url():
    render_template('loading_spinner.html')
    sleep(3)
    return redirect("https://youtube.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need python, better solution do this via JavaScript.

Comment: do you want to redirect to the same window? or it should open in newtab? Javascript will be the best solution for it.

Comment: @Pygirl I want to redirect to the same window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a timeout in javascript. Here is the sample
**loding_spinner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
<script>
   function myFunction() {
   location.replace("https://youtube.com")
   }

   setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(); }, 3000);
</script>
</html>
```

**python Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def redirect_to_url():
  return render_template('loading_spinner.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you don't have to set timer. let it run once the url gets changed it will go away on its own.

Comment: I think he want's to display loding mask for 3 seconds, that's why I have put timer logic.